# The specified location does not contain information about your hardware [xp]

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, printer

I'm remotely installing printer drivers to a clients set of laptops (over Teamviewer). They are all XP. They have an Oki c5650 printer. I download the driver from the Oki website. The first and second laptop works fine.

I go on to the third laptop (incidentally a notebook - Compaq). Do the exact same thing as the other two laptops. Add printer, new TCP/IP port - 192.168.1.75. "Have disk" for driver, select the exact same driver as the other two - error: The specified location does not contain information about your hardware.

Why on earth would it say that? I've done nothing different to the other two machines.

Comment: Could this be a 64bit version of XP on the laptop?

Comment: Ahh could be, never thought to check!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that springs to mind is that there is a 64Bit OS on this laptop, which would obviously mean it needed a different driver (and if it's XP 64, then they likely don't exist!).